# Linux installation problems - R

Tags: linux, r, installation

I see the following error while installing R on one of my Centos VE:

```
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.0-5.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Requires: libtcl8.4.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.0-5.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Requires: libtk8.4.so()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried installing R with the following commands:

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
yum install R
```

Any help ?

Comment: You need to install `tcl` and `tk` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install these two Dependency files first-

```
tcl-devel
tk-devel
```

Follow the following commands

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install tcl
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install R
```